# Nginx subdomain with port https REST post request

Tags: nginx, redirect, port, subdomain

I am running a server and am using nginx. My app is runs on apache tomcat.
This is the configuration I have and it works:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    
    if ($host = "199.99.99.999") {
        return 404;
    }

    client_max_body_size 8M;

    server_name test.example.com www.test.example.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        
        proxy_connect_timeout       1800;
        proxy_send_timeout          1800;
        proxy_read_timeout          1800;
        send_timeout                1800;
        fastcgi_read_timeout        1800;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_redirect http://localhost:8080 https://test.example.com;
    }

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
}
```

However, recently I added my own backend service (gradle project) that is running on a different port (85). Now for some time it was only needed locally, however there are new some REST post request that are going straight to the backend service on port 85, instead of tomcat.

So non ssl link somehow works. I don't understand how or why it does work:
http://test.example.com:85/api/MyController

However ssl link doesn't work:
https://test.example.com:85/api/MyController

My questions are:

1. Why does the http request with port 85 even work when I didn't configure anything in nginx for it to work.
2. How do I make the https request with port 85 work?

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: http to port 85 is not coming into nginx but rather goes directly into the app. No ssl configured there, right?

Comment: Ok I think I get it. Even without nginx http link would work, and nginx is only neede for ssl? So I need to configure nginx to listen to port 85 and then redirect it to ssl port?